# Does the cost of using a skill trainer depend on your current skill level?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've recently come across my first skill trainer ([Arnick Arduna](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Arnick_Arduna), in the Gorhart inn). I was looking forward to upping my Detect Hidden skill, but then I saw that I would have to part with around 15K in gold (I didn't even have 1000 gold at the time). My Detect Hidden skill at the time was 2, and I'm wondering if that has anything to do with the steep price.

That is to say, does the cost of training a skill at a trainer increase with the amount of points you already have invested in that skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, no. Every trainer I've been to has charged me 15,120 gold. (Though it might bear mentioning that I've only encountered Basic trainers so far).

But even if higher leveled trainers *do* cost more, your current skill doesn't affect the price - either you are in the proper range (and can pay the static price) or you're too inexperienced or too experienced, and can't buy it at all.

Comment: I can't verify Atm but I am pretty sure the higher level trainers cost more than the basic ones.

Comment: So the cost is agnostic to your actual skill level. That's what I wanted to know, thanks!

Comment: @Aubergine I wouldn't worry too much about it. In a few hours of gameplay, you'll literally have more gold than you can possibly do things with.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter at all. The price is all the same.